# Can I aggregate all stylesheets core, contrib and custom into one single stylesheet?

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

Is there any way to avoid Drupal from serving multiple stylesheets and instead bundle them together? I am going to look into https://www.drupal.org/project/webpack

I want to avoid all the multiple @imports if possible that get created by the modules. Reason I want to do this is I am archiving my site with wget and I want to have less stylesheet links to monitor.

[image]

Comment: Did you try aggregation on `admin/config/development/performance` ?

Comment: I tried it. I still end up with 5 css files and 5 js files. However it does mean that the files are not using @import which is defintiely an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable aggregation of css by going to `admin/config/development/performance`

This is the best Drupal 7 can do without the need for any contrib module

You can also try [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) which gives some more advanced aggregation.